# .persist() returns no errors, but where is my persisted data?

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, jakarta-ee, stripes

In my DAO implementation I'm doing `Stripersist.getEntityManager().persist(client);`, this doesn't seem to return any errors, but I can't find the data that it persists.

My client object looks like this :

```
@Entity
public class Client implements Serializable
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @Column
    private String name;

    //accessors etc here
 ...
 }
```

I have one persistence unit and is as follows

```
<persistence-unit name="stripes" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
      <!-- Tell JPA to use Hibernate -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
       <!--Hibernate settings -->
        <properties>
         <!--Autodetect entity classes -->
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
         <!--Automatically create the SQL schema -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
       <!--Tell Hibernate to use HSQLDB -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"
        value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"
        value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />
       <!--Configure the JDBC database connection-->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/salestracker" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="admin"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="admin"/>
            <property name="jdbc.batch_size" value="0"/>
       <!--Configure the connection pool--> 
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Like I say, I've set a breakpoint on the `.persist(client);`, the client has a `name` set, and has `null` for an `id` (otherwise I'd have used `.merge()`), therefore I'm not sure as to why the data is not persisted?

If I look at the table, `CLIENT`, it has 0 rows.

```
SELECT * FROM ADMIN.CLIENT

Executed successfully in 0.001 s.
Line 1, column 1

Execution finished after 0.001 s, 0 error(s) occurred.
```

Is it possible that the entity is being persisted, but the transaction is not being committed?

Thanks

EDIT : Here is some logging info

```
INFO: 09:24:32,002 DEBUG JpaTransactionManager:285 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@4e65ad52] for JPA transaction
INFO: 09:24:32,002 DEBUG JpaTransactionManager:371 - Creating new transaction with name [com.jameselsey.salestracker.service.ClientService.persistClient]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
INFO: 09:24:32,002 DEBUG JDBCTransaction:82 - begin
INFO: 09:24:32,003 DEBUG ConnectionManager:444 - opening JDBC connection
INFO: 09:24:32,003 DEBUG JDBCTransaction:87 - current autocommit status: true
INFO: 09:24:32,003 DEBUG JDBCTransaction:90 - disabling autocommit
INFO: break
INFO: 09:24:40,960 DEBUG SessionImpl:247 - opened session at timestamp: 12600914809
INFO: 09:24:40,961 DEBUG JDBCTransaction:82 - begin
INFO: 09:24:40,962 DEBUG ConnectionManager:444 - opening JDBC connection
INFO: 09:24:40,965 DEBUG JDBCTransaction:87 - current autocommit status: true
INFO: 09:24:40,966 DEBUG JDBCTransaction:90 - disabling autocommit
INFO: 09:24:40,993 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:585 - opening JDBC connection
INFO: 09:24:40,993 DEBUG DriverManagerConnectionProvider:132 - opening new JDBC connection
INFO: 09:24:40,996 DEBUG DriverManagerConnectionProvider:138 - created connection to: jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/salestracker, Isolation Level: 2
INFO: 09:24:40,997 DEBUG SQL:111 - select next_hi from hibernate_unique_key for read only with rs
INFO: 09:24:41,001 DEBUG SQL:111 - update hibernate_unique_key set next_hi = ? where next_hi = ?
INFO: 09:24:41,006 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:606 - closing JDBC connection (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)
INFO: 09:24:41,007 DEBUG TableHiLoGenerator:87 - new hi value: 0
INFO: 09:24:41,007 DEBUG AbstractSaveEventListener:135 - generated identifier: 1, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.TableHiLoGenerator
INFO: 09:24:41,036 DEBUG JpaTransactionManager:730 - Initiating transaction commit
INFO: 09:24:41,037 DEBUG JpaTransactionManager:451 - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@4e65ad52]
INFO: 09:24:41,037 DEBUG JDBCTransaction:134 - commit
INFO: 09:24:41,038 DEBUG JDBCTransaction:227 - re-enabling autocommit
INFO: 09:24:41,038 DEBUG JDBCTransaction:147 - committed JDBC Connection
INFO: 09:24:41,039 DEBUG ConnectionManager:427 - aggressively releasing JDBC connection
INFO: 09:24:41,039 DEBUG ConnectionManager:464 - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
INFO: 09:24:41,047 DEBUG JpaTransactionManager:539 - Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
INFO: 09:24:41,047 DEBUG ExecutionContext:183 - Transitioning to lifecycle stage ResolutionExecution
INFO: 09:24:41,048 DEBUG HttpCacheInterceptor:183 - Looking for HttpCache on com.jameselsey.salestracker.action.ViewClientAction.save()
INFO: 09:24:41,160 DEBUG ExecutionContext:183 - Transitioning to lifecycle stage RequestComplete
INFO: 09:24:41,161 DEBUG JDBCTransaction:186 - rollback
INFO: 09:24:41,161 DEBUG JDBCTransaction:227 - re-enabling autocommit
INFO: 09:24:41,162 DEBUG JDBCTransaction:197 - rolled back JDBC Connection
INFO: 09:24:41,162 DEBUG ConnectionManager:427 - aggressively releasing JDBC connection
INFO: 09:24:41,162 DEBUG ConnectionManager:464 - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
INFO: 09:24:41,163 DEBUG OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter:119 - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
INFO: 09:24:41,163 DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils:313 - Closing JPA EntityManager
```

Comment: what's your transaction manager and how is it configured.
set showSql=true and see what queries are executed to the database.

Comment: Can you post the code where the merge happens?

Comment: I'm not using merge at the moment, only persist as I just have empty tables

Comment: Of course I was talking about persist, not merge :) Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Freely quoting the Java EE specs, whenever you say `em.persist(obj)`, it *doesn't* necessarily mean a direct SQL query to the database. It means that the entity named `obj` will have a *persistent identity*, thus it's state will be saved and flushed to the persistent store in some time, maybe right after your `persist` call, maybe after the transaction, it depends on your JPA provider. This could mean that if you call `persist` to an entity and pause the application with a breakpoint, your persisted data won't be in the database immediately.

If you'd like to have a SQL query right after persisting an entity, you could run `em.flush()`.

Answer (score 2):

Did you do this, after calling `persist()`?

```
Stripersist.getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
```